# XML error ":1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog" running from jar - but is OK in Eclipse. Why?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, groovy, byte-order-mark

I have been round and round and round looking for this odd situtation. I have tried various suggestions, mostly related to BOM issues, but I still get this 'BOM-like' error, when running from an executable jar file, that was exported from Eclipse. I don't get the error when running the code in Eclipse. The platform is Windows Server 2012r2

The actual parsing is being done in a Groovy class using the XmlSlurper, whose input is an xml string passed from Java. I am assuming that the problem is in the Java code that creates the string.

I got this error when I ran my first test in Eclipse. Eventualy, I checked the encoding in np++ (used to edit the file, but not create it) and it said "UTF-8 + BOM". I changed that to "UTF-8" rather than refresh my memory on handling BOMs, from some years ago. That solved the problem.

When I export the Eclipse project to an executable jar, I get the ' Content is not allowed' parse exception from the same xml file (OK, it's copied to a different folder).

I have tried using the Apache BOMInputStream to wrap the InputStream from the file (this worked for me in the past). This time it doesn't.
The result from (BomInputStream) #getBOM() is *false*. But, it's also false when I set the encoding to "UTF-8 + BOM"! (that's running in Eclipse and the jar)

In case it's relevant, the start of the Groovy code is:

```
def ClientConfig parse (String clientConfigXML) {
  def config = new XmlSlurper(false, false).parseText(clientConfigXML);
```

I'd be delighted to find that someone can help. I  haven't included the Java code as it's the normal stuff you find in Q&A for this topic, and it's full of commented-out code right now.
Time for bed...

Best regards, John

[Answer:

If you try to parse a .properties file that starts with a comment, in the belief that it is xml, you get the ".1:1: Content is not allowed..." error from the  xml parser. That was due to me being careless. Thanks for the prompt below that got me to check this basic fact.

The good thing to come out of this, is that my code is now BOM-proof. I will keep the use of the BOMInputStream - eliminated a little technical debt.]

Comment: Are you able to parse the xml in browser

Comment: Check if clientConfigXML is null or empty before trying to parse. Also, print it to stdout to check what's really trying to parse.

Comment: Aaaargh! Thanks @LuisM

Comment: Aaaargh! Thanks @LuisMuñoz. I had checked this, but only in Eclipse. So I deployed a new jar file. What was displayed wasn't xml at all... it was the original .properties file that I had used to configure the app, which I have converted to xml. In the bat file that launches the app, I'd forgotten to change the -D arg for the config file. Hang head in shame. 

Maybe there is one useful thing to come out of this... you can get this xml parser error when the input is not xml, as well as when there is a BOM. Thank you very much for prompting me to do what I should have done already. John

Comment: Could you generalize what you did and post it as the answer to the question please?

Comment: I wrote the above comment in response to the request to post it as the answer. Touble is that I can't see any way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the value of -D parameter (for the 'properties' file) in the `.bat` file that launched the jar file. It was still referring to a `.properties` file, what I had replaced by an XML file. This error is what you get when you read what should be an XML file, but is, in fact, a properties file.